How to Configure a Postfix Email Server to Send Emails Securely via Port 465 Instead of Port 25
My Linux server cannot open port 25 due to a restrictive policy. I have been advised to send emails using port 465. I configured Postfix accordingly, including TLS settings and relayhost configuration, but sending emails still fails.
My Current Configuration:
TLS Parameters:
# TLS parameters
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt

Relayhost Configuration:
relayhost = [mail.mydomain.com]:465
mydestination = mail.$mydomain, mydomain.com, iZ0xi7acfsuw7o16lyv8e0Z, localhost.localdomain, localhost

master.cf Configuration:
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
        -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
        -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
        -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
        -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem

smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
        -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
        -o smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
        -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
        -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes

The Key Error in Logs:
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.mydomain.com[xx.xxx.xx.xxx]: 454 4.7.1 <target@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<root@iZ0xi7acfsuw7o16lyv8e0Z> to=<target@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.mydomain.com>

2024-12-18T01:15:26.044309+08:00 iZ0xi7acfsuw7o16lyv8e0Z postfix/smtp[429557]: E379AC1D0E: to=<target@gmail.com>, relay=mail.mydomain.com[xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:465, delay=587, delays=587/0.02/0.26/0.01, dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mail.mydomain.com[xx.xxx.xx.xxx] said: 454 4.7.1 <target@gmail.com>: Relay access denied (in reply to RCPT TO command))
2024-12-18T01:15:26.045320+08:00 iZ0xi7acfsuw7o16lyv8e0Z postfix/smtpd[429561]: disconnect from mail.mydomain.com[xx.xxx.xx.xxx] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=4/6

I would appreciate assistance in resolving this issue so that Postfix can successfully send emails via port 465.
